# using an enum to "list" singleton sub class

Tags: java, design-patterns

Ok so I began a project and I want to represent adventurers ("Aventuriers" in French) each of the adventurers are unique and each have a special action.

I've came up with this :

```java
public abstract class Aventurier {
    public abstract void specialAction();
}
```

```java
public enum AvanturierE {

    NAVIGATEUR("Navigateur",Navigateur.getNavigateur()),
    PILOTE("Pilote",Pilote.getPilote()),
    INGENIEUR("Ingenieur",Ingenieur.getIngenieur());

    AvanturierE(String nom, Aventurier aventurier) {
        this.aventurier = aventurier;
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    Aventurier aventurier;
    String nom;

    public Aventurier getAventurier() {
        return aventurier;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Navigateur extends Aventurier {

    private Navigateur() {}

    static Navigateur navigateur = new Navigateur();

    public static Navigateur getNavigateur() {
        return navigateur;
    }

    @Override
    public void specialAction() {}
}
```

```java
public class Pilote extends Aventurier {

    private Pilote() {}

    static Pilote pilote = new Pilote();

    public static Pilote getPilote() {
        return pilote;
    }

    @Override
    public void specialAction() {}
}
```

```java
public class Ingenieur extends Aventurier {

    private Ingenieur() {
    };

    static Ingenieur ingenieur = new Ingenieur();

    public static Ingenieur getIngenieur() {
        return ingenieur;
    }

    @Override
    public void specialAction() {}
}
```

It works as expected but as it's not a personal project I want to know if it's a valid design. And if not if there is a good alternative.

Comment: Are you asking perhaps for some kind of code review?

Comment: It looks like a poor model of the real world. There is more than one engineer, more than one pilot in existence in the real world. These classes are not good examples of singletons.

Comment: DodgyCodeException is right. Read more about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern